# Entity many to many check if relation exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have two tables: Items and Colors. They have a many to many relation. In a CheckBoxList that displays colors, I want to check those that are associated to the item shown.

```
using (var db = new ProwebModel.Entities())
{
    var colors = db.Colors;

    foreach (ListItem color in ((CheckBoxList)(fv.FindControl("cblColors"))).Items)
    {
        var itemId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        var colorNumber = Convert.ToInt32(color.Value);
        color.Selected = colors.Where(t => t.ColorNumber == colorNumber).First().Items.Where(t => t.ItemId == itemId).Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I was wondering about this line :

```
color.Selected = colors.Where(t => t.ColorNumber == colorNumber).First().Items.Where(t => t.ItemId == itemId).Count() > 0;
```

Is there any better way to check if the association exist?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I chaged my code to something better.. I think. Is there still a better way to do this?

```
using (var db = new ProwebModel.Entities())
{
     var itemId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
     var ItemColors = db.Items.First(t => t.ItemId == itemId).Colors.ToList();

     foreach (ListItem color in ((CheckBoxList)(fv.FindControl("cblColors"))).Items)
     {
          var colorNumber = Convert.ToInt32(color.Value);
          color.Selected = ItemColors.Where(t => t.ColorNumber == colorNumber).Count() > 0;
     }
}
```

Many thanks!

**Code update**

```
using (var db = new ProwebModel.Entities())
{
    var itemId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    var ItemColors = db.Items.First(t => t.ItemId == itemId).Colors.ToList();

    foreach (ListItem color in ((CheckBoxList)(fv.FindControl("cblColors"))).Items)
    {
        var colorNumber = Convert.ToInt32(color.Value);
        color.Selected = ItemColors.Any(t => t.ColorNumber == colorNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line could at least be rewritten as :

```
color.Selected = colors.First(t => t.ColorNumber == colorNumber).Items.Any(t => t.ItemId == itemId);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the Any() function. I changed the line for this -> color.Selected = ItemColors.Any(t => t.ColorNumber == colorNumber);

Comment: Hi, Your post has been edited while I was writing the answer, but I kept my first answer because it was showing the two possible improvements and it wasn't hard to apply them to the new code.